# simple Objective-C script to open a url

Tags: objective-c, ios

im trying to open a url with object c my code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ithinksw.com/"]];
return 0;
}
```

but when i try to compile it i get these errors

```
hello.c: In function 'main':
hello.c:4: error: expected expression before '[' token
hello.c:4: error: 'NSWorkspace' undeclared (first use in this function)
hello.c:4: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
hello.c:4: error: for each function it appears in.)
hello.c:4: error: expected ']' before 'openURL'
hello.c:4: error: stray '@' in program
```

im extremal new to this so any help would be great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you targetering to iphone, so you have to use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL] instead of NSWorkspace.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif

// ...

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url];
#endif
```

And don't forget to add Foundation framework to include and link section.

Comment: So like this? #include <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> #include <Foundation/Foundation.h>   #link <Foundation/Foundation.h> and yes his is for iPhone :P

Comment: Yep, that is include. In addition you have to add Foundation framework to your project.

Comment: @lewisdenny Are you trying to compile file without Xcode? In such case you can specify framework right to the gcc:

$ gcc main.m -framework Foundation -o myexecutable

Answer (score 2):

You have to

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Also, the file name should be `hello.m` so that the compiler knows it deals with Objective-C here.

And make sure to link your binary to the Foundation framework.

Answer (score 1):

If your are new to iOS programming I highly recommend using some of Apples templates in xCode as a basis for your development.

NSWorkspace is a MacOS X construct. I don't think there is any iOS equivalent.

Take a look at the CP193P videos on iTunesU to get you started on iOS programming - happy programming!

Comment: Awesome thanks for the advice and encouragement. p.s great link to CP193P iv already started watching :)